# Conditional Probability on Hydrology

Tags: probability, statistics

I love doing probability problems. But I stuck on this following problem and couldn't proceed.
Probability that solar radiation intensity will reach a threshold value is 0.25 for rainy days and 0.8 for non rainy days. It is also known that probability of rainy days is 0.36. What is the probability that the threshold intensity of solar radiation will be reached?

Can anyone please help me to solve this out?

Comment: Try [Bayes' theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)

Comment: You love doing probability problems, but are stuck on this one?  Why?  What about it in particular is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $T$ be the event that the threshold is reached. Let $R$ be the event that it is a rainy day, and $R'$ be the opposite. Then

$$P(T)=P(T|R)P(R)+P(T|R')P(R')$$

Can you finish it from here?

---

More hints:

> $$P(T|R)=0.25\\P(T|R')=0.8\\P(R)=0.36\\P(R')=1-P(R)=0.64$$

---

What is this equation? It is called the [Law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). Essentially what it says is $$P(\text{event }A)=P(A|B_1)P(B_1)+P(A|B_2)P(B_2)+...+P(A|B_m)P(B_m)\tag1$$ where all the $B_i$'s are disjoint events, meaning $P(B_i\text{ and }B_j)=\begin{cases}1\text{ if } i=j\\0\text{ if }i\neq j\end{cases}$, and $P(B_1\text{ or }B_2\text{ or }...\text{ or }B_m)=1$.

Rather than get confused with the formula, try and imagine what it means. Suppose that the disjoint events are rolls on a die, so $B_1$ is rolling a $1$, and so on until $B_6$, which is rolling a 6. Then reading the equation $(1)$ from left to right, it says:

*The probability that event A occurs is given by: the probability that A happens given that the die rolled 1, or the probability that A happens given that the die rolled 2, or..., or the probability that A happens given that the die rolled 6*.

From this you can tell that you don't change anything by applying this formula, you just split the probability up into lots of different cases, but since these cases are all different to each other (disjoint) and cover all possibilities, this equation works.

Comment: Can you give a short explanation about how you formulate this?

Comment: @ShahidulIslam I have edited my question to add this